# GUI does not get updated before initiating sleep function in a loop

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, user-interface, sleep

I am a bit riddled with this problem why my GUI (Windows form) does not get updated before calling a sleep function. I know this locks up the code. But I want to update a textbox before calling it for 5 seconds. After these 5 seconds I get back in that loop and adding a point after my loading string so it looks a bit dynamic. Here is the code! :)

```
// First check if the plc bit, that says if there is still an order active, is still set. If so then we wait a couple seconds.
                            var bitorder = Main.PIOGetValue(jbmis.IO_GET_INPUT, "BoxManInStarted");
                            int counter = 1;
                            string loadingpoints = "";
                            while(bitorder != 0 && counter <= 5)
                            {
                                //TODO multithreaded
                                //MessageBox.Show("Waiting for previous order to be stopped" + loadingpoints);
                                //Context.UserMessageService.ShowMessage("Waiting for previous order to be stopped" + loadingpoints, "Waitingfororder");

                                loadingpoints = loadingpoints + ".";
                                tbScannedEANPick.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
                                tbScannedEANPick.Text = "Waiting" + loadingpoints;
                                tbScannedEANPick.UpdateLayout();
                                bitorder = Main.PIOGetValue(jbmis.IO_GET_INPUT, "BoxManInStarted");
                                counter ++;

                                // Wait 5 seconds
                                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                            }

                            // After couple retries if the bit is still high reset ean grid and throw exception
                            if(counter > 5 && bitorder == 1)
                            {
                                ResetEanGrid();
                                throw (new Exception(String.Format("Bit 'BoxManInStarted' is still high; PLC order is still active?")));
                            }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you want your GUI to be responsive (that includes repainting), you will need to do your processing on another thread.

Comment: In your GUI thread do the while loop, inside the while loop call a function from another class which does the stuff and afterwards refresh your textbox after each looptrough.

Comment: Quickest fix: Call `Application.DoEvents();` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`, this is an old technique and it _still_ works...If I post it as an answer I will get downvotes.

Comment: Never! DoEvents!!! Never!!! update your GUI from a different thread and try `tbScannedEANPick.Invalidate();` instead of `tbScannedEANPick.UpdateLayout();`

Comment: But if I use another thread then my while loop will go on and be finished very fast (5 loops)? Or not?